# Link activity on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm coding a website which has 5 `divs`.

```
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="three"></div>
<div class="four"></div>
<div class="five"></div>
```

Somewhere on the website, i want to put two links.

```
<a href="">PREVIOUS</a>
<a href="">NEXT</a>
```

I need the "previous link" (when clicked) to show me the div before to the present one and it should do the same with "next link".

Comment: Learn from here: http://jsfromhell.com/classes/data-slider

Comment: Post some tried code..

Comment: "before" as the element above it in the DOM, or "before" as in the element clicked and shown before the current one ?

Comment: Ass the element above it in the DOM, sorry for my lack of english.

Answer (score 4):

Here you go this is an example:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Qw75j/7/)

HTML :

```
    <button id="prev" disabled="disabled">Prev</button>
    <button id="next">Next</button>
    <hr /> 

<div id="main">   
    <div id="div1" class="first current">Div 1</div>
    <div id="div2">Div 2</div>
    <div id="div3" class="last">Div 3</div>    
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$('#next').click(function() {
        $('.current').removeClass('current').hide()
            .next().show().addClass('current');
        if ($('.current').hasClass('last')) {
           $('#next').prop('disabled', true);
        }
        $('#prev').prop('disabled', false);
    });

    $('#prev').click(function() {
        $('.current').removeClass('current').hide()
            .prev().show().addClass('current');
        if ($('.current').hasClass('first')) {
            $('#prev').prop('disabled', true);
        }
        $('#next').prop('disabled', false);
    });
```

Comment: @piruchex Please like my answer pressing UP

Comment: I'll like your answer when you fix you all the errors. Change `attr()` to `prop()` and use `prop('disabled', false)` not `null`.

Answer (score 1):

The current classes you have in your div's should probably be ID's, lets give all these div's a common class (I also added ID's to your links):

```
<div id="one" class="divCycle"></div>
<div id="two" class="divCycle"></div>
<div id="three" class="divCycle"></div>
<div id="four" class="divCycle"></div>
<div id="five" class="divCycle"></div>

<a href="#" id="divPrev">PREVIOUS</a>
<a href="#" id="divNext">NEXT</a>
```

Then we can add click handlers to your buttons:

```
$("#divPrev").click(function() {
    var visibleDiv = $(".divCycle:visible");

    //verify there is a previous div
    if (visibleDiv.prev(".divCycle").length) {
        visibleDiv.prev(".divCycle").show();
        visibleDiv.hide();
    }
});

$("#divNext").click(function() {
    var visibleDiv = $(".divCycle:visible");

    //verify there is a next div
    if (visibleDiv.next(".divCycle").length) {
        visibleDiv.next(".divCycle").show;
        visibleDiv.hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the anchors ID's matching jQuery methods, and it's easy:

```
var elems = $('.one, .two, .three, .four, .five');

$('#prev, #next').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var n = elems.filter(':visible').hide()[this.id]();
        n = elems.is(n) ? n : this.id=='next' ? elems.first() : elems.last();
    n.show();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2K72H/1/)

Comment: `[this.id]()` looks like a maintainability nightmare *shudder*

Comment: Well, you know what they say: *Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code will be a violent psychopath who knows where you live.* - the code posted here is not the most readable i've seen, is all i'm saying :) A novel idea, sure...

Comment: As I'm the guy who ends up maintaining my code, it's not an issue, it's much more readable to me then any of the other answers. The brackets clearly tells that the ID is used as a method, and the ID's for the event handler is in the selector, so everything is right there if you know how javascript works.

Comment: Thanks, this is an example of what i need. http://bit.ly/14eskAx But i cannot get it done in my site http://bit.ly/19Ckx55

Comment: Your site doesn't have jQuery included, or anything else, it only has impress.js ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery you should have a look at [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) and [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to scroll to the desired div you can use jQuery's `scrollTo()`.

Answer (score 0):

**In HTML**

```
    <button id="prev" disabled="disabled">Prev</button>
    <button id="next">Next</button>
    <hr /> 

<div id="main">   
    <div id="div1" class="first current">Div 1</div>
    <div id="div2">Div 2</div>
    <div id="div3">Div 3</div>  
    <div id="div2">Div 4</div>
    <div id="div3" class="last">Div 5</div>  
</div>
```

**Place it in JScript**

```
$('#next').click(function() {
    $('.current').removeClass('current').hide()
        .next().show().addClass('current');
    if ($('.current').hasClass('last')) {
        $('#next').attr('disabled', true);
    }
    $('#prev').attr('disabled', null);
});

$('#prev').click(function() {
    $('.current').removeClass('current').hide()
        .prev().show().addClass('current');
    if ($('.current').hasClass('first')) {
        $('#prev').attr('disabled', true);
    }
    $('#next').attr('disabled', null);
});
```

**And in your CSS**

```
#div2,#div3,#div4,#div5{
    display:none;
}
```